# Correct file permissions for /var/www/html/ for multiple users - permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, nginx

I have been struggling for hours with an annoying permissions issue (feel like it's ALWAYS permissions that's holding me back).

I am trying to ensure that I can create/read/execute inside `/var/www/html`. The folder is owned by `www-data`. My user is a member of the `www-data`-group. My deployment service is also a member of `www-data`. So I cannot change ownership to my own user since we're multiple users who need to have access to the folder.

I have tried the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
sudo usermod -a -G www-data my_user
groups my_user #verify that I am a part of the group
```

Still if I try to create a folder within `/var/wwwhtml/` folder I get: `Permission denied`

I am stuck! It seems a though multiple people have been facing this issue before, some solutions require to change ownership to my current user, but that's not what I want. I want www-data to own the folder. Also I need multiple people to be able to write in the path.

Comment: Well have you re-login after the `usermod` command? Assuming you are logged in as `my_user`, you should see different outputs from `groups` and `groups my_user` before relogin.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to re-login for the changes to take effect (after adding a user to a group)